# Encapsulate LINQ query for different Repositories to avoid repeated code

Tags: c#, linq

I have actually this tree method in my app:

```
public decimal GetPayrunAllowanceYTDValue(Guid employeeId, Guid payrunId, Guid payItemId, DateTime paymentDate)
{
    var payrunPayItem = _firstRepository.FilterBy(x => x.EmployeeId == employeeId
                                                    && x.PayrunsId != payrunId
                                                    && x.PayItemId == payItemId
                                                   && x.EffectiveDate <= paymentDate, null)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.EffectiveDate).FirstOrDefault();
         return payrunPayItem.YTD ?? 0;
}

public decimal GetPayrunDeductionsAndSupersYTDValue(Guid employeeId, Guid payrunId, Guid payItemId, DateTime paymentDate)
{
   var payrunPayItem = _secondRepository.FilterBy(x => x.EmployeeId == employeeId
                                                  && x.PayrunsId != payrunId
                                                  && x.PayItemId == payItemId
                                                  && x.EffectiveDate <= paymentDate, null)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.EffectiveDate).FirstOrDefault();
   return payrunPayItem.YTD ?? 0;
}

public decimal GetPayrunCompanyContributionYTDValue(Guid employeeId, Guid payrunId, Guid payItemId, DateTime paymentDate)
{
   var payrunPayItem = _thirdRepository.FilterBy(x => x.EmployeeId == employeeId
                                                 && x.PayrunsId != payrunId
                                                 && x.PayItemId == payItemId
                                                 && x.EffectiveDate <= paymentDate, null)
                         .OrderByDescending(x => x.EffectiveDate).FirstOrDefault();
   return payrunPayItem.YTD ?? 0;
}
```

As you can see, this 3 functions are exactly the same with only one difference, they are querying to different repositories. I'm trying to refactor this to some generic function, like this one:

```
public decimal GetYtdValue<T>(T repository, Guid employeeId, Guid payrunId, Guid payItemId)
            where T : IReadonlyRepository<FirstRepositoryType>, IReadonlyRepository<SecondRepositoryType>, IReadonlyRepository<ThirdRepositoryType>
{
   var payrunPayItem = repository.FilterBy(x => x.EmployeeId == employeeId
                                                && x.PayrunsId != payrunId
                                    && x.PayItemId == payItemId, null).OrderByDescending(x => x.EffectiveDate).FirstOrDefault();
            return (payrunPayItem.YTD ?? 0);
        }
```

The problem here is that I'm getting an error because there is an "Ambiguous reference" since all the repositories have the same base class with those properties.

So, there is a way to refactor this and have a more elegant-not repeated code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem here is that I'm getting an error because there is an "Ambiguous reference" since all the repositories have the same base class with those properties.

Then just use the base class as your parameter.

```
public decimal GetYtdValue(MyRepoBaseClass repository, 
                           Guid employeeId, Guid payrunId, Guid payItemId)
```

Since the Linq expressions are identical other than the repository, the repositories have something in common.  In this case it is a shared base class.  If they did not share a base class, you could instead express that commonality as an interface that they all implement.

**UPDATE**

> I can't do that since the last property is in each individual repository class (in the last line, payrunPayItem.YTD)

Then define an interface `IRepository` that includes YTD and have each concrete repository implement that interface.

```
public decimal GetYtdValue(IRepository repository, 
                           Guid employeeId, Guid payrunId, Guid payItemId)
```

Comment: I can't do that since the last property is in each individual repository class (in the last line, payrunPayItem.YTD). So, I can't query the repository of the base class because I will miss the property. At the same time, I'm trying to pass a IReadOnlyRepository<Type> not only a the Type.